# ubuntu : restore folders in var directory

Tags: data

I accidentally deleted all folders in var directory using rm -rf var/* through terminal, Is any way to restore that folders.Please help me.

Comment: if you dont have back up , i dont think its possible, if you can update the question with why you need those folders, may be community will help you......

Comment: actually i want to run that command in my magento root folder but accidentaly i run in direct folder please any idea

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498597/magento-var-folder

Comment: i deleted var not under magento root

Comment: oh, you deleted from server, sorry i misunderstood, please post question once in https://superuser.com/questions and https://askubuntu.com/ , i hope you will get some solution, next time please login with `user` instead  of `root`......